# Why is a union of two interfaces not same as interface of the union (pertaining specifically to my example below)?

Tags: typescript, types

In short, why aren't the following two types not equivalent?

```
type A = {
    prop: string
} | {
    prop: number
};

type B = {
    prop: string | number
}
```

An object of type `A` is assignable to type `B` but an object of type `B` is not assignable to type `A`. Why is that?

Comment: See [ms/TS#30170](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30170) and [ms/TS#39169](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39169) and [this](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052#issuecomment-258653766);  `A` is assignable to `B` because each union member of `A` is assignable to `B`.  But TS doesn't attempt to verify the other direction for non-discriminated unions, because *in general* it's not possible to do such propagation (it only would work here because it's a single property). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the links and your comment answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is effectively a design limitation of TypeScript, although the relevant issues in GitHub tend to be marked as "working as intended" or "not a defect".  See [microsoft/TypeScript#12052](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052) and other linked issues (such as [microsoft/TypeScript#30170](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30170)).

Let's say we have a non-union type `T`, and a (non-[discriminated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)) union type `U0 | U1 | U2 | ⋯ | UN` where each of `U0 extends T`, `U1 extends T`, `U2 extends T`, ⋯,  `UN extends T` is *true*, and where each of `T extends U0`, `T extends U1`, `T extends U2`, ⋯, `T extends UN` is *false*.  (This is the case  in your example where `T` is `{prop: string | number}` and `U0` is `{prop: string}` and `U1` is `{prop: number}`.)

Then acceptability of assigning `U0 | U1 | U2 | ⋯ | UN` is easy for the compiler to verify.  Each of the union members is assignable to the non-union, so the whole thing is assignable.  At no point does the compiler need to try to inspect more than one union member from `U` at a time; nor does it need to try to split/distribute the non-union `T` into a union.  So the assignability of `A` to `B` is not an issue.

---

On the other hand, TypeScript can't generally perform the sort of analysis that would be necessary to see that `T` is assignable to `U0 | U1 | U2 | ⋯ | UN`.  In general it isn't true (e.g., `{c: D | E, f: G | H}` is *not* assignable to `{c: D, f: G} | {c: E, f: H}`), and when it *is* true the only way to see so might involve merging pairs or triplets of the union members, or trying to break apart `T` into an exponentially large number of equivalent union members.

For the single property case like `{prop: string}` and `{prop: number}` and `{prop: string | number}`, this isn't very expensive, but such cases are apparently not common enough to be worth accommodating (according to the linked GitHub issues).  And it gets worse when you have more properties like `{c: D | E, f: G | H, i: J | K}`; that would require generating [Cartesian products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of unions like `{c: D, f: G, i: J} | {c: E, f: G, i: J} | {c: D, f: H, i: J} | {c: E, f: H, i: J} | ⋯ | {c: E, f: H, i: K}`, so the amount of work goes way up and the likelihood of finding a match goes way down.  So the compile doesn't even try.  In your example, that means the assignment from `B` to `A` is rejected.

Note that if the union is a *discriminated* union, it scales better, because more potential union members can be pruned earlier, so more work is done in these cases.  This is described in [the TypeScript 3.5 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking) and implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30779](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30779).  But `A` is not a discriminated union (neither `string` nor `number` are valid discriminant properties) so it doesn't apply here.  Even where it applies, the analysis bails out if the union it starts to generate has more than 25 members, so it's easy enough to write discriminated unions that fail the same way.

So it's a design limitation; the type checker disallows some acceptable assignments from non-unions to unions because it's too expensive to perform the analysis needed to verify that the assignment is indeed acceptable.